# Why does this function have implicit any return type?

Tags: typescript

with `--strict` this

```js
const arr = [''];
arr.map(_ => Observable.of({ json: () => [''] }));
```

results in this error 
`[ts] Function implicitly has return type 'any' because it does not have a return type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in one of its return expressions.`

however this is okay

```js
const arr = [''];
const empty = () => [''];
arr.map(_ => Observable.of({ json: empty }));
```

Why is that?

Comment: `{ json: () => [''] }` is this a variable? why are you using arrow function in it?

Comment: yes, I want to set `json` to be a `function () { return ['']; }`